# TortoiseGit detected that the file does not exist but is staged added or modified

Tags: tortoisegit

[image: Problem in TortoiseGit]

I can't find any question asked online so I decide to post a new question.
You can see the problem in the picture
The file does exist but TortoiseGit say the opposite.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If this message appears then TortoiseGit could not find the file in the working tree. Are you sure that the file exists?

Comment: Yes, it exists. If I choose to restore, my local change will be reverted. If I choose to remove then the file become missing and the local file become unknown. I choose Ignore for all cases and it seems to work ok.

Comment: Is the full pathname longer than 260 characters?

Comment: yes it is. But I already run the command "git config --system core.longpaths true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseGit is not capable of handling pathnames longer than 260 chars in all cases (as of version 2.3.0). This seems to be one of the case where it doesn't work, see https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1017.

With the next version (>= 2.3.6) this specific problem will be solved.

Comment: With the next version (>= 2.3.6) this specific problem will be solved.

Comment: The preview release 2.3.6 was just published.

Comment: It seems to be not yet completely fixed in TortoiseGit version 2.12. I still get this message for long paths while trying to commit or to resolve conflicts. The last comment in the linked issue (see the answer) is "No, there are a lot of more fixes needed. Just one blocker got resolved.".

Answer (score 1):

If I choose to restore, my local change will be reverted. If I choose to remove then the file become missing and the local file become unknown. Ignore for all cases works ok for me.